# потеря фокуса editText в listView

Tags: android, listview

**UPDATE**
код такой: но при выборе 2 edit, фокус возвращается в 1 edit. пробовал играться параметрами clearFocus(), но не помогает..

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_tovar, parent, false);
        currentPosition = position;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.edit_name_tovar = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_name_tovar);
        holder.edit_mark_tovar = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_mark_tovar);
        holder.edit_cost_tovar = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_cost_tovar);
        holder.add_button_tovar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_button_tovar);
        holder.trash_button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.trash_button);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    emptyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.custom_items_list, R.id.items, list_tov);
    holder.edit_name_tovar.setAdapter(emptyAdapter);

    holder.title.setText("Товар_1");

    holder.edit_mark_tovar.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    holder.edit_cost_tovar.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

    if (holder.edit_mark_tovar.hasFocus()) {
        holder.edit_mark_tovar.addTextChangedListener(new AddListenerOnTextChange(holder.edit_mark_tovar));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    if (holder.edit_cost_tovar.hasFocus()) {

        holder.edit_cost_tovar.addTextChangedListener(new AddListenerOnTextChange(holder.edit_cost_tovar));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //holder.edit_cost_tovar.setMask("dd ddd dd");
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.edit_mark_tovar:
            //holder.edit_cost_tovar.clearFocus();
            if (hasFocus) {
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (lastFocussedPosition == -1 || lastFocussedPosition == currentPosition) {
                            lastFocussedPosition = currentPosition;
                            holder.edit_mark_tovar.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                }, 200);

            } else {
                lastFocussedPosition = -1;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.cost_tovar:
           //holder.edit_mark_tovar.clearFocus();
            if (hasFocus) {
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (lastFocussedPosition == -1 || lastFocussedPosition == currentPosition) {
                            lastFocussedPosition = currentPosition;
                            holder.edit_cost_tovar.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                }, 200);

            } else {
                lastFocussedPosition = -1;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Listview xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_tovar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:layout_weight=".50">
```

EditText xml :

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_cost_tovar"
        android:hint="Введите сумму"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        style="@style/item_list_tovar"/>
```

Comment: UPDATE: код переписал, но проблема осталась не до конца решенной, при использовании    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants", фокус стоит только на 1 edit, на второй нажимаю, но фокус все равно возвращается в 1 edit, а без этого параметра, приходится 2 раза кликать чтоб не получить фокус
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_tovar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:layout_weight=".50">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема известная, есть такой хак:

```
 private int lastFocussedPosition = -1;
 private Handler handler = new Handler();

 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  // ...

 edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (lastFocussedPosition == -1 || lastFocussedPosition == position) {
                        lastFocussedPosition = position;
                        edittext.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }, 200);

        } else {
            lastFocussedPosition = -1;
        }
      }
    });

    return convertView;
 }
```

Comment: String   enter = ((EditText) v).getText().toString(); а так можно выдергивать данные тут? вроде как отдельный поток же?

Comment: Таски запущенные через handler выполняются в ui треде

Comment: можно узнать почему используется значение -1 ?

Comment: Просто значение по умолчанию, когда позиция не установлена

Comment: можете подсказать по update ?

Comment: Если сделать двойное нажатие (вниз например) то фокус будет мигать между двумя последними элементами, как это исправить??